# Accuracy converging to one in neural network (tensorflow.keras)

Tags: loss-functions, accuracy, tensorflow, keras

I was wondering if somebody would be able to shine a light on accuracy converging to 1 relatively quickly during training.

I am working on some new data and this is the first time i have seen this. I have attached the imaged of accuracy and loss (actual and validation set).

I am running a multi-label network where the data fits in to either class one, two or three. The code I am using is as follows:

```
model= tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=416, input_dim=20539, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=288, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=576, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="SGD", metrics=['accuracy'])

history=model.fit(X_trainERSC.values, y_trainERSC,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=32,
          verbose=1,
          validation_split=0.15,
          callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)],shuffle=True)
```

Now the network trains fine and everything seems ot be ok and in a similar trend to data i have worked with previously. However, unlike the previous data which converges to about 97% for accuracy, the accuracy in this data converges to 1. I was wondering if this is normal? I know this seems vague, but i am not sure what to make of this and if for, accuracy and loss, extremely low loss as well as convergence to 1 is normal?

Many thanks!!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect accuracy on training data doesn't mean much, but you seem to have admirable accuracy out-of-sample, too (~90%). Accuracy isn't always the best measure of performance (imagine if you have 99% of your observations belonging to one category), but that looks good to me.

Converging to exactly 1 means that you've fit to some of the noise. That is pretty much always going to happen, and we validate on out-of-sample data to make sure that the overfitting isn't too severe. Again, your out-of-sample accuracy is pretty high, so in-sample data having a perfect accuracy score would not concern me.

(I'm assuming that 90% validation accuracy is high performance for your task. It might not be, for instance, if you're doing an MNIST classifier.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and for clarifying this! yes that is a good point. I will bare this in mind. 'Converging to exactly 1 means that you've fit to some of the noise. That is pretty much always going to happen' thank you for clarifying this... i actually have never seen this in any network i have built so wasnt sure if this was expected?.. 90% is very good considering my task! :) its not the MNIST dataset haha! thanks again!